# Trouble in 'Retrieving token..' in google speech translate api

Tags: ios, swift, google-speech-api, google-cloud-translate

I am trying to run speech translate [App](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ios-docs-samples/tree/master/speech-to-speech) for iOS from GitHub which uses google speech API.
When the app starts to run a pop-up appearing with a message "Retrieving token". In-app folder 'ApplicationConstants.swift' file has also a variable for token.

Can anyone tell me where I can find this token?[image]

Comment: are you talking about the google cloud speach API?